# How to use map inside map in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have object like this:

[{a:1, rows:[]},{a:2,rows:[]}]

I want to map the the a's as table columns and rows as cells.

I'm trying like this:

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {doc.map(({
        _id, rfqID, supplier, notes, rows,
      }) => (
          <th>{supplier}</th>
        ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {rows.map(({ offerPrice }) => (
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{offerPrice}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
```

But I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: rows is not defined`
What is the correct syntax to map this table with headers & items?

Comment: syntax you got right. But the variable `rows` you are referring is not in the scope.

Comment: @Villemh can you please change the marked answer as the marked answer now is not correct?

Answer (score 4):

Since doc is array of objects you need to do map on doc and again map on rows to display offerprice

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {doc.map(({
        _id,
        rfqID,
        supplier,
        notes,
        rows,
      }) => 
        <th key={_id}>{supplier}</th>
      )}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {doc.map(({ rows }) => 
    rows.map((offerPrice, index)  =>
      <tr key={`Key-$(index)`}>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{offerPrice}</td>
      </tr>)
  )}
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find a way how to get access to rows inside the same map function. Was little bit confusing. This works just fine.

Comment: @villemh Not sure this makes sense since you'll basically stack the rows for each element in your array on top of each other. It doesnt look like it will relate to your table head.

Comment: @vhflat You are absolutely right. My bad I didn't properly look at OP data. I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: I tried to delete my answer but unfortunately I am not able to do because its accepted answer